# Silverstripe 2.3.1 will only save Date Field as 1970-1-1

Tags: php, silverstripe

When I save an DataObject with a Date field from a form it gets saved as 1970-1-1.

It's a standard

```
public static $db = array(
  'MyDate' => 'Date'
);
```

then

```
$form->saveInto($obj);
$obj->write();
```

although both stages (saveinto,write) seem to change the value to 1970.
I realise this is not much to go on so I guess I'm after suggestions for how to debug it.

it's using the ecommerce and payment modules.

Comment: are you sure you got the version number right? there are some wines getting better over the years, but software mostly isn't

Comment: Sounds like the date is invalid since it's falling back to the epoch default. Can you add any debug outputs or provide some code?

Comment: hope my comment above didn't sound overly rude, it wasn't meant that way - just a note you really should consider upgrading (current version is 3.0), at least for the sake of security?

Comment: Not at all. Will definitely be upgrading. But for the moment It's important to fix this problem as quickly as possible.

Answer (score 0):

The docs (http://api.silverstripe.org/2.4/class-Date.html) state "The field currently supports New Zealand date format (DD/MM/YYYY), or an ISO 8601 formatted date (YYYY-MM-DD)"

If the date is being saved as epoch default, it is likely that it's being passed in in an incorrect format. This could be due to a locale difference between your server and the date format that the data type expects.

You'll need to see the format of $obj->MyDate and manipulate it before calling $form->saveInto() so the date is saved in the correct format.